# Program won't continue to run after user 'login'

Tags: java, menu

So I am creating a program that allows the user to login to a 'Wages application'. The username, password and account number have been hard coded and the user is allowed three attempts to login. If three attempts fail, then the program will terminate. If the user successfully logs in, the program will continue to run and open up a menu. The problem I am having is that the program won't continue to run (won't open up the menu) once the user has successfully logged in. I am probably missing something very basic, but I can't seem to find out where I have gone wrong. Any corrections are appreciated.

The menu is not complete, I am just trying to make it run correctly at the moment.

Thanks

**My code;**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Assignment4Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      final int Username = 3387;
      final int Password = 5183;
      final int AccountNumber = 22334455;

       int EnteredUsername;
       int EnteredPassword;
       int EnteredAccountNumber;
      for(int s=0;s<=3;s++)
      {if (s<3)
      {System.out.println("Enter Username");
      EnteredUsername = console.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Username Entered is " + EnteredUsername);
      System.out.println("Enter Password");
      EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Password Entered is " + EnteredPassword);
      System.out.println("Enter Account Number");
      EnteredAccountNumber = console.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Account Number Entered is " + EnteredAccountNumber);
      if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
              && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {
          System.out.println("Welcome");
          break;
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Wrong Username, Password or Account Number. Please try again.");
      }
      }
          else
      {
          System.out.println("3 incorrect enteries detected. Program is terminating, goodbye!"); 
     }
 }


class Menu extends JFrame {

    JMenuBar menubar;

    JMenu TransferAnAmount;
    JMenuItem TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount;

    JMenu ListRecentTransactions;
    JMenuItem ShowList;

    JMenu DisplayCurrentBalance;
    JMenuItem ShowBalance;

    JMenu ExitProgram;
    JMenuItem Exit;

    public Menu() {

        setLayout (new FlowLayout());

        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar (menubar);

        TransferAnAmount = new JMenu("Transfer An Amount");
        menubar.add(TransferAnAmount);

        ListRecentTransactions = new JMenu("List Recent Transactions");
        menubar.add(ListRecentTransactions);

        DisplayCurrentBalance = new JMenu("Display Current Balance");
        menubar.add(DisplayCurrentBalance);

        ExitProgram = new JMenu("Exit Program");
        menubar.add(ExitProgram);

        TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount = new JMenuItem("Transer an amount to another account");
        TransferAnAmount.add(TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount);

        ShowList = new JMenuItem("Show List");
        ListRecentTransactions.add(ShowList);

        ShowBalance = new JMenuItem("Show Balance");
        DisplayCurrentBalance.add(ShowBalance);

        Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit Program");
        ExitProgram.add(Exit);

        event e = new event();
        Exit.addActionListener(e);

    }

        class event implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);

            }

        }

        public void main (String args[]) {
            Menu gui = new Menu();
            gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gui.setSize(600,300);
            gui.setVisible(true);

        }

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved your `Menu` class up out of the `main` method, and made it a `static inner class`.

For clarity, I renamed it `MyFrame` and renamed the `main` method to `displayGui`.

Let me know if you don't understand anything.

```
public class Assignment4Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int Username = 3387;
        final int Password = 5183;
        final int AccountNumber = 22334455;

        int EnteredUsername;
        int EnteredPassword;
        int EnteredAccountNumber;
        for (int s = 0; s <= 3; s++) {
            if (s < 3) {
                System.out.println("Enter Username");
                EnteredUsername = console.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Username Entered is " + EnteredUsername);
                System.out.println("Enter Password");
                EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Password Entered is " + EnteredPassword);
                System.out.println("Enter Account Number");
                EnteredAccountNumber = console.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Account Number Entered is " + EnteredAccountNumber);
                if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
                        && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {
                    System.out.println("Welcome");
                    new MyFrame().displayGui();
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Wrong Username, Password or Account Number. Please try again.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("3 incorrect enteries detected. Program is terminating, goodbye!");
            }
        }
    }

    static class MyFrame extends JFrame {

        JMenuBar menubar;

        JMenu TransferAnAmount;
        JMenuItem TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount;

        JMenu ListRecentTransactions;
        JMenuItem ShowList;

        JMenu DisplayCurrentBalance;
        JMenuItem ShowBalance;

        JMenu ExitProgram;
        JMenuItem Exit;

        public MyFrame() {

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            menubar = new JMenuBar();
            setJMenuBar(menubar);

            TransferAnAmount = new JMenu("Transfer An Amount");
            menubar.add(TransferAnAmount);

            ListRecentTransactions = new JMenu("List Recent Transactions");
            menubar.add(ListRecentTransactions);

            DisplayCurrentBalance = new JMenu("Display Current Balance");
            menubar.add(DisplayCurrentBalance);

            ExitProgram = new JMenu("Exit Program");
            menubar.add(ExitProgram);

            TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount = new JMenuItem("Transer an amount to another account");
            TransferAnAmount.add(TransferAnAmountToAnotherAccount);

            ShowList = new JMenuItem("Show List");
            ListRecentTransactions.add(ShowList);

            ShowBalance = new JMenuItem("Show Balance");
            DisplayCurrentBalance.add(ShowBalance);

            Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit Program");
            ExitProgram.add(Exit);

            event e = new event();
            Exit.addActionListener(e);

        }

        class event implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);

            }

        }

        public void displayGui() {
            MyFrame gui = new MyFrame();
            gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gui.setSize(600, 300);
            gui.setVisible(true);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi this worked great, but originally the program terminates after three incorrect login attempts whereas the code you provided continues to open the menu even after three incorrect attempts. Is there a way to keep the program so that it terminates after three incorrect login attempts and only open the menu if successfully logged in. Other than that it works fine, thank you.

Comment: Ok, fixed! Please click the green arrow to "accept" the answer if you are now happy with it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the `Menu` object, it is never created or used.  Not if you use the same entry point (`public static void main()`) that the login uses.

You have a second entry point which creates and uses the `Menu` object but this is not the one you are using.

You probably want to move the second entry point code into the first, after a successful login

```
  if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
          && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {
      System.out.println("Welcome");
      Menu gui = new Menu();
      gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      gui.setSize(600,300);
      gui.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After succesfull login, you have a break (exit) in your code. Currently, How do you relate the login and the creation of the menu in your code?

```
  if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
          && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {
      System.out.println("Welcome");
      break;
  }
```

You should instance a new Menu after the sucessfull login. You must execute the code placed in the second `main` method:

```
  if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
          && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {
      System.out.println("Welcome");

   // Create Menu
    Menu gui = new Menu();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(600,300);
    gui.setVisible(true);
  }
```